# How to get IMEI Number in IOS 7 devices programmatically

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, mobile, imei

I wrote the code for getting IMEI number in iPhone/iPad devices, it worked well IOS 6. Once I updated the OS version to IOS 7, app getting crash while executing IMEI number retrieval code. Is there any changes required to get the IMEI in IOS 7 devices?

Here is my code:

```
struct CTResult it;
CFMutableDictionaryRef kCTDict;
conn = _CTServerConnectionCreate(kCFAllocatorDefault, ConnectionCallback,NULL);
_CTServerConnectionCopyMobileEquipmentInfo(&it, conn, &kCTDict);
NSLog (@ "kCTDict is %@", kCTDict);
CFStringRef meid = CFDictionaryGetValue(kCTDict, CFSTR("kCTMobileEquipmentInfoMEID"));
NSLog (@ "kCTMobileEquipmentInfoMEID is %@", meid);
CFStringRef mobileId = CFDictionaryGetValue(kCTDict,CFSTR("kCTMobileEquipmentInfoCurrentMobileId"));
NSLog (@ "kCTMobileEquipmentInfoCurrentMobileId is %@", mobileId);
```

Comment: NSString *imeinumber = [[NetworkController sharedInstance] IMEI];

Answer (score 1):

I am not very sure about IMEI number in iOS7 Apple changed the way they provide the Unique Identifier. But you should not be getting IMEI in first place as you're using private API and this is against Apple rules.

To get unique identifier for device you should use UDID. This will always return the same id across all your apps running on the same phone.

Comment: Actually, UDID is deprecated on iOS7 (along with Open UDID and MAC Address). The correct way is to replace it with UUID, identifierForVendor or advertisingIdentifier, depending of your needs.

Check the following to see how you can get the UUID and store it in the keychain:

https://github.com/joseandro/TitaniumiOSUniqueIDs/blob/master/Classes/ComJoseandroUniqueidsModule.m#L173